# Replace switch statement with more concise logic

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have a chunk of code like

```
        switch (newDir)
        {
            case "left":
                {
                    this.dx = -1; this.dy = 0;
                    break;
                }
            case "up":
                {
                    this.dx = 0; this.dy = 1;
                    break;
                }
            case "right":
                {
                    this.dx = 1; this.dy = 0;
                    break;
                }
            case "down":
                {
                    this.dx = 0; this.dy = -1;
                    break;
                }
            default: // never happens
                break;
        }
```

which is meant to set the direction that an object in my game is moving. I think it's nicely readable, self-explanatory, but it's too bulky for my liking. I'm wondering if you guys know of a fancy way for me to consolidate it to

```
this.dx = ... ; 
this.dy = ... ;
```

Maybe something that involves bitwise operators or maps or something.

Comment: if this code works, you should put it on this site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for codereview.

Comment: @FelixKling ...which aren't explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Simon: The link seems to confirm that this question would be a good fit for CodeReview (even though I didn't actually suggest to move it there). See also [What are the differences between Stack Overflow, Programmers, and Code Review?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266341/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling: just because it is a good fit doesn't make it off-topic here. Questions can fit multiple sites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object as a map

```
var directions = {
  'left': {
    dx : -1, dy : 0
  },
  'right': {
    dx : 1, dy : 0
  },
  'up': {
    dx : 0, dy : 1
  },
  'down': {
    dx : 0, dy : -1
  }
};

this.dx = directions[newDir].dx;
this.dy = directions[newDir].dy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it...

```
dir_map = {right:0,up:1,left:2,down:3}
dirs = [[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]]

dir = dir_map[newDir] // and keep it as number from now on. Never get back to string.
this.dx += dirs[dir][0]
this.dy += dirs[dir][1]
```

Even if neutral direction is required:

```
if (dir != null) {
    this.dx += dirs[dir][0]
    this.dy += dirs[dir][1]
}
```